# Does system integrity protection prevent nvram(8) from setting -x as a boot argument for safe mode?

Tags: macos, launchd, nvram, safe-mode

When pre-release macOS Sierra is in safe mode with `-x` as a boot argument in NVRAM, the following command works as expected:

`sudo nvram boot-args="-v"`

---

When Sierra is booted in normal mode, the following command is rejected by the OS:

`sudo nvram boot-args="-x -v"`

Please:

- **is that rejection to be expected with SIP?**

As a workaround, I typically use Recovery OS Terminal to run the nvram command.

Comment: I have to wonder if this might be related precisely to SIP and the changing role of **launchctl** handling reboot requests over a three year period leading up to the T2 chip intriduction with iMac Pro and  macOS 10.13 High Sierra. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/232343/

Comment: Did you try turning off SIP and rerunning the command? I can confirm it works on my Mojave machine with SIP disabled.

Comment: The part before the "---" is not relevant.  `boot-args="-v"` always works, even in normal mode. 
The problem is that `sudo nvram boot-args="-x"` does not work with the error `nvram: Error setting variable - 'boot-args': (iokit/common) not permitted`